# how to link docker container to each other with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to setup a mongo replica set with docker-compose. For the replica set the containers have to know each other.

I tried in `docker-compose.yml`

```
    dbreplicasetpart1:
      image: mongo:2.6.8
      expose:
        - '27018'
      links:
        - replicasetpart2
        - replicasetpart3
      cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN

    dbreplicasetpart2:
      image: mongo:2.6.8
      links:
        - replicasetpart1
        - replicasetpart3
      expose:
        - '27019'
      cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN
...
```

I get an circular import message. But if I remove the back-link to dbreplicasetpart1 I can't ping from dbreplicasetpart2 to dbreplicasetpart1.
What is the solution?

Comment: All the answers here predate the new Docker Networking introduced in Docker 1.9. What you do now is to create a network first and pass it to the docker-compose up. I'll add an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Updated for Docker 1.10**

Docker 1.10 allows the definition of networks within the compose file.
Here's the updated code

```
version: "2"

services:
  replica1:
    image: mongo:2.6.8
    container_name: replica1
    networks:
      - my-net
    ports:
      - "27018"
    environment:
      REPLICA2_URL: "http://replica2:27019"
  replica2:
    image: mongo:2.6.8
    container_name: replica2
    networks:
      - my-net
    ports:
      - "27019"
    environment:
      REPLICA1_URL: "http://replica1:27018"

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

**Previous answer for Docker 1.9**

As of Docker 1.9, the solution to this is to create a custom network and pass it to the `docker-compose up` command.

1. Create a network

   `docker network create --driver bridge my-net`
2. Reference that network as an environment variable (`${NETWORK}`)in the docker-compose.yml files. Eg:

```

```
replica1:
  image: mongo:2.6.8
  container_name: replica1
  net: ${NETWORK}
  ports:
    - "27018"
  environment:
    REPLICA2_URL: "http://replica2:27019"

replica2:
  image: mongo:2.6.8
  container_name: replica2
  net: ${NETWORK}
  ports:
    - "27019"
  environment:
    REPLICA1_URL: "http://replica1:27018"
```

```

Note that `replica1` in `http://replica1:27018` will resolve to the ip address of the replica1 service (container). No need to hardcode ip addresses; An entry for replica1 is automatically added to the /etc/host of the replica2 container. Same goes for the replica1 container. Docker will add an entry for replica2 in its /etc/host file.

3. Call docker-compose, passing it the network you created

   `NETWORK=my-net docker-compose up -d -f docker-compose.yml`

I've created a **[bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#a-bridge-network)** above which only works within one node (host). Good for dev. If you need to get two nodes to talk to each other, you need to create an **[overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/)**. Same principle though. You pass the network name to the docker-compose up command.

Comment: Due to the changes in Docker 1.9 this is the way better solution. Hence this should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: Trying to get the same thing working for mysql, have tried the above, maybe I'm missing something, can't get it working.  Would greatly appreciate if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059109/docker-compose-run-two-instance-of-mysql

Answer (score 13):

You should use the ambassador pattern:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/ambassador_pattern_linking/

Basically you create an intermediate component that bridges both of them together. You can see an example that we use with Spring Cloud's Eureka discovery service:

```
ambassador:
  image: cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  command: "-name eureka_1 -name eureka2_1 "

eureka:
  links:
    - "ambassador:eureka2"

eureka2:
  links:
    - "ambassador:eureka"
```

For simplicity, I only copied the links

Comment: With configuration like yours I got this error: `ambassador_1 | time="2015-03-30T11:34:06Z" level=info msg="Error creating proxy for %s %s:%s - %vdockerfoo_dbreplicasetpart1_1172.17.0.17927017listen tcp 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use" ambassador_1 | time="2015-03-30T11:34:06Z" level=info msg="Error creating proxies for container dockerfoo_dbreplicasetpart1_1"`

Comment: Could you post your config with the ambassador? The hack below is not the best approach as the IP addresses might change in a different environment.

Comment: Miguel, we figured out to use your ambassador solution, see my config in the answer below.

Comment: In a docker-compose environment, you have to adjust your -name arguments for docker-grand-ambassador, like @MichaelK. solution below shows: <COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME>_<service name>_1, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/ and -p flag https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/docker-compose/

Comment: This does not work in Mac OSX because Docker is running in a VM, so there's no access to `/var/run/docker.sock`. What would I do to solve this on Mac?

Comment: I was told that mounting the docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock` to a container is inherently evil, as this would allow that container to control **all** local docker containers and implies a huge security hole.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS APPROACH FOR >=Docker 1.10 Take a look at the bridge network answer

Comment: doesn't work for me ERROR: Circular dependency between ambassador and ...

Answer (score 1):

Without updating the `docker-compose.yml` file,

```
docker network connect docker-compose-network-you-want-to-connect conatianer-name-from-another-docker-compose
```

More [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)

Answer (score 0):

We figured out to use the solution with the ambassador. It is indeed the more comfortable solution.
The configuration that works for us:

```
amba1:
  image: cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  command: "-name cucumber_dbreplicasetpart1_1"

amba2:
  image: cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  command: "-name cucumber_dbreplicasetpart2_1"

amba3:
  image: cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  command: "-name cucumber_dbreplicasetpart3_1"

dbreplicasetpart1:
  image: 'mongo:2.6.8'
  hostname: dbreplicasetpart1
  command: >
    bash -c
    '
      mongod --fork --logpath mongo.log --smallfiles --replSet rs1
      echo "
        printjson(
          rs.initiate(
            {
              _id : \"rs1\",
              members : [
                {_id : 0, host : \"dbreplicasetpart1:27017\"},
                {_id : 1, host : \"dbreplicasetpart2:27017\"},
                {_id : 2, host : \"dbreplicasetpart3:27017\"},
              ]
            }
          )
        );
      " | mongo;
      tail -f mongo.log
    '
  links:
    - "amba2:dbreplicasetpart2"
    - "amba3:dbreplicasetpart3"

dbreplicasetpart2:
  image: 'mongo:2.6.8'
  hostname: dbreplicasetpart2
  command: >
    bash -c
    '
      mongod --fork --logpath mongo.log --smallfiles --replSet rs1
      echo "
        printjson(
          rs.initiate(
            {
              _id : \"rs1\",
              members : [
                {_id : 0, host : \"dbreplicasetpart1:27017\"},
                {_id : 1, host : \"dbreplicasetpart2:27017\"},
                {_id : 2, host : \"dbreplicasetpart3:27017\"},
              ]
            }
          )
        );
      " | mongo;
      tail -f mongo.log
    '
  links:
    - "amba1:dbreplicasetpart1"
    - "amba3:dbreplicasetpart3"

dbreplicasetpart3:
  image: 'mongo:2.6.8'
  hostname: dbreplicasetpart3
  command: >
    bash -c
    '
      mongod --fork --logpath mongo.log --smallfiles --replSet rs1
      echo "
        printjson(
          rs.initiate(
            {
              _id : \"rs1\",
              members : [
                {_id : 0, host : \"dbreplicasetpart1:27017\"},
                {_id : 1, host : \"dbreplicasetpart2:27017\"},
                {_id : 2, host : \"dbreplicasetpart3:27017\"},
              ]
            }
          )
        );
      " | mongo;
      tail -f mongo.log
    '
  links:
    - "amba1:dbreplicasetpart1"
    - "amba2:dbreplicasetpart2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what should still work in Docker 1.7.1 (in case you stuck with CentOS 6):

```
etcd:
  image: elcolio/etcd:latest
skydns:
  image: outrider/skydns
  links:
    - etcd
  environment:
    ETCD_MACHINES: "http://etcd:4001"
    SKYDNS_DOMAIN: "docker"
    SKYDNS_PATH_PREFIX: my
    SKYDNS_NDOTS: 0
    SKYDNS_VERBOSE: "true"
    SKYDNS_ADDR: 0.0.0.0:53
  expose:
    - 53

my-service:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "dns_add my-service && ping my-service"
    links:
      - etcd
      - skydns
```

`dns_add` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# This script configures resov.conf to use
# "skydns" name server with "docker" domain
# and adds a service name specified in the first argument
SERVICE_NAME=$1

waitforit () {
  HOST=$1
  PORT=$2
  TIME_OUT=${3:-30};
  END=$(($(date "+%s+$TIME_OUT")))
  while [ $(date "+%s") -lt $END ]
    do nc -z -w1 $HOST $PORT && break
  done
  return $END
}

# Use skydns to resolve names
echo "nameserver `resolveip -s skydns`" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "search docker" >> /etc/resolv.conf

# Put yourself to DNS
ETCD_HOST=etcd
ETCD_PORT=4001
waitforit $ETCD_HOST $ETCD_PORT
HOST_IP=`resolveip -s $HOSTNAME`
apk update && apk add curl
curl -XPUT http://$ETCD_HOST:$ETCD_PORT/v2/keys/my/docker/$SERVICE_NAME -d value="{\"host\":\"$HOST_IP\"}"
```

Here's an explanation:

1. We set up our own DNS server in a container
2. We configure our containers to use that server
3. We configure that DNS server using special HTTP requests