# Circular import error Docker Compose OSX VM linking two containers

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I have several containers I'm running with Docker Compose. Two of them need to talk to each other, so I've linked them like this in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
serviceone:
  links:
    - servicetwo

servicetwo:
  links:
    - serviceone
```

But, it throws an error saying "Circular import between x and y".

This post solves the issue for people who are using Linux: [how to link docker container to each other with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307645/how-to-link-docker-container-to-each-other-with-docker-compose)

Because it makes use of `/var/run/docker.sock`, this doesn't work on Mac because on Mac, Docker is running in a VM, and `/var/run/docker.sock` doesn't exist. How can I fix this circular import problem on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Links aren't designed to work with circular imports. One solution is to use a different service discovery method.

Another solution is to try out the latest [docker-compose 1.5.0rc1 release](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.5.0rc1) with `-x-networking` (requires docker 1.9.0-rc1).

The new networking support will let you do circular requests.  See [the networking docs](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/ae3c66baed422916000e05e6c6218a5a82b43f19/docs/networking.md) for more information.