# Connecting to Postgres docker container from docker-compose file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 projects. The first contains this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# pg/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_DB: pg
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    networks:
      - some_net

volumes:
  postgres-data:

networks:
  some_net:
    driver: bridge
```

The second project has this docker compose file:

```
# pg_client/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres_client:
    image: tmaier/postgresql-client
    command: postgres://pguser@localhost:5432/pg
    networks:
      - pg_some_net

networks:
  pg_some_net:
    external: true
```

The [`tmaier/postgresql-client`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/postgresql-client) image is extremely simple, it has PostgresSQL installed and runs the command `psql DOCKER_COMMAND` at build time. In my case this is `psql postgres://pguser@localhost:5432/pg`.

I can connect to my Postgres db just fine from the command line:

```
$ psql postgres://pgmuser@localhost:5432/pg
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.

pg=#
```

But when the `postgres_client` container attempts to connect (after running `docker-compose up`), it fails saying

```
postgres_client_1  | psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
postgres_client_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
postgres_client_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
postgres_client_1  | could not connect to server: Address not available
postgres_client_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
postgres_client_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Is there something special about docker-compose that I need to account for when writing my Postgres connection URI?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393779/connect-two-instances-of-docker-compose. Might help you. Each docker compose sets up an isolated network.

Comment: @AshharHasan Ahhh thank you for finding that. Sounds like I need to ensure both docker-compose files lie in the same network

Comment: @AshharHasan Unfortunately, it looks like adding the containers to the same network does not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hostname of postgres should resolve to `postgres` instead of `localhost`. You can try

```
command: postgres://pguser@postgres:5432/pg
```

Comment: Woked! Under the hood it looks like docker assigns a separate IP address (not localhost), so when it's in the same network I need to reference the name of the container rather than `localhost`

Comment: @bpgeck That's a docker compose thing. It sets up hostnames. Does not work with plain standalone containers unles you pass --link.