# How to dockerize two applications talking to each other via a http server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### TL;DR

How can we setup a docker-compose environment so we can reach a container under multiple, custom defined aliases? (Or any alternative that solves our problem in an other fashion.)

### Existing setup

We have two applications<sup>†</sup> (nodejs servers), each behind an HTTP reverse proxy (Nginx), that need to talk to each other. On localhost, configuring this is easy:

- Add /etc/hosts entries for ServerA and ServerB:

  - 127.0.0.1 server-a.testing
  - 127.0.0.1 server-b.testing
- Run ServerA on port e.g. 2001 and ServerB on port 2002
- Configure two virtual hosts, reverse proxying to ServerA and ServerB:

  ```
  server {   # Forward all traffic for server-a.testing to localhost:2001
      listen      80;
      server_name server-a.testing;
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:2001;
      }
  }
  server {   # Forward all traffic for server-b.testing to localhost:2002
      listen      80;
      server_name server-b.testing;
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:2002;
      }
  }
  ```

This setup is great for testing: Both applications can communicate each other in a way that is very close to the production environment, e.g. `request('https://server-b.testing', fn);` and we can test how the HTTP server configuration interacts with our apps (e.g. TLS config, CORS headers, HTTP2 proxying).

### Dockerize all the things!

We now want to move this setup to docker and docker-compose. The `docker-compose.yaml` that would work in theory is this:

```
nginx:
  build: nginx
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  links:
   - server-a
   - server-b
server-a:
  build: serverA
  ports:
   - "2001:2001"
  links:
   - nginx:server-b.testing
server-b:
  build: serverB
  ports:
   - "2002:2002"
  links:
   - nginx:server-a.testing
```

So when ServerA addresses `http://server-b.testing` it actually reaches the Nginx which reverse proxies it to ServerB. Unfortunately, circular dependencies are not possible with links. There are three typical solutions to this problems:

1. [use ambassadors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307645/how-to-link-docker-container-to-each-other-with-docker-compose)
2. [use nameservers](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/666#issuecomment-109580454)
3. [use the brand new networking (`--x-networking`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Neither of these work for us, because, for the virtual hosting to work, we need to be able to address the Nginx container under the name `server-a.testing` and `server-b.testing`. What can we do?

<sub>(†) Actually it's a little bit more complicated – four components and links – but that shouldn't make any difference to the solution:</sub>

- <sub>testClient (-> Nginx) -> ServerA,</sub>
- <sub>testClient (-> Nginx) -> ServerB,</sub>
- <sub>ServerA (-> Nginx) -> ServerB,</sub>
- <sub>testClient (-> Nginx) -> ServerC,</sub>

Comment: How about a combination of 3 (`--x-networking`) and https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy instead of nginx? You would set the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable on each of `server-a` and `server-b`. If you needed more granular control of the nginx configuration, you could separate out docker-gen and the nginx container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Link you **server-a** and **server-b** container to nginx with  --link server-a:server-a --link server-b:server-b
2. Update nginx conf file with

   location /sa
              proxy_pass http://server-a:2001

   location /sb
          proxy_pass http://server-a:2001

When you link two containers, docker adds "conatiner_name container_ip" to /etc/hosts file of the linking container. So, in this case, *server-a* and *server-b* is resolved to their respective container IPs via /etc/hosts file.

And you can access them from http://localhost/sa or http://localhost/sb