# docker-compose run two instance of mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to run two instances of mysql using docker-compose.

I'm running MySQL in a Docker container and I have another Docker container running a python script to access the MySQL database.

One works fine on port 3306.  In order to get two working, I thought I would just run the other one on a different port.  But when I change it to a different port (e.g. 6603), but when I do, I get the below error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql:6603' (111 Connection refused)
```

I have read every question on s.o. I can find that seems relevant but none of the solutions work.  I feel certain the fix will involve changing a line or two of configuration but I've spent many hours on this so far so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The docker-compose script is below (works fine if 6603 is replaced with 3306).

```
server:
   build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: Docker/ServerDockerfile
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
   links:
    - mysql:mysql
   volumes:
    - ../py:/app
   tty: true

 mysql:
  image: mysql
  expose:
    - "6603"
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
   MYSQL_DATABASE: project
  volumes:
    - ./MySQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    - ./MySQL/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And it is being accessed like this:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password',
                          host='mysql',
                          port="6603",
                          database='project')
```

Comment: Try `"6603:3306"`.

Comment: How?  I have tried expose: -"6603:3306" but that is invalid (gives the error services.mysql.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]')  And I tried using ports: - "6603:3306" but that didn't change the original result (connection refused).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have eventually found a couple of ways that work.  The neatest one is for each app to create a network and connect the containers to it.

If each app uses a different network then mysql can run on 3306 on that Docker network and can be accessed on mysql://3306 from app1 and mysql2://3306 from app2.  (Assuming you name you give the mysql service for app 2 is mysql2).

The Docker file with the new lines is below:

```
server:
 build:
context: ../
dockerfile: Docker/ServerDockerfile
ports:
 - "8080:8080"
volumes:
 - ../py:/app
tty: true
networks:
 -net

mysql2:
 image: mysql
 environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: project
 volumes:
  - ./MySQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  - ./MySQL/data:/var/lib/mysql
 networks:
  -net

networks:
 net:
  driver: bridge
```

The Docker file for the second app is identical except the names are different (I put a 2 after each for simplicity).

```
 server2:
  build:
   context: ../
   dockerfile: Docker/ServerDockerfile
  ports:
 - "8081:8080"
 volumes:
 - ../py:/app
tty: true
networks:
 -net2

mysql2:
 image: mysql
 environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: project
 volumes:
  - ./MySQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  - ./MySQL/data:/var/lib/mysql
 networks:
  -net2

networks:
 net2:
  driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify another port for MySQL by modifying its `my.cnf` file.